# Cannot find cause of concurrency issues

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, database-concurrency

I am getting a concurrency violation on my updatecommand when I try to save a datatable back to the database.  I have spent hours trying to find a solution but it escapes me.  I am changing one column in about 90% of my rows in a 4200 plus row datatable. I am using a datatable that has a primarykey. I am also using a sqlitedatadapter:

```
  Dim cbActiveCustomers As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(ActiveCustomersAdapter)
  ActiveCustomersAdapter.Update(DTActiveCustomers)
```

I fill the datatable with this

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Status = 'Active'"
    ActiveCustomersAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    ActiveCustomersAdapter.Fill(DTActiveCustomers)
```

I fill the table, loop through the table changing one date field by adding an increment variable to a date column and then try to save as above.  There are no concurrent users and no other activity on the database.
I am obviously not doing something correctly but have not found a pointer as to what I am missing.

Your help is appreciated.
Brad

Edit:
This error occurs when this command is executed:

```
ActiveCustomersAdapter.Update(DTActiveCustomers)
```

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Thanks C.P
 - Further Edit:
InnerException = Nothing
When I expand the exception there are four red crosses at TargetSite:
1. CustomAttributes-> Method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.
2. IsSecurityCritical -> DirectCast(ex.TargetSite, System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo).IsSecurityCritical cannot be called in this context.
3. IsSecuritySafeCritical = Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecuritySafeCritical cannot be called in this context.
4. IsSecurityTransparent = Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityTransparent cannot be called in this context.

The UpdateCommand produces this command:

> UPDATE [main].[sqlite_default_schema].[Customers] SET   [NextCallDue]
>   = @param1 WHERE (([PrimaryKey] = @param2) AND   ([CustomerNumber] = @param3) AND   ((@param4 = 1 AND [Zone] IS NULL) OR ([Zone] =
>   @param5)) AND   ((@param6 = 1 AND [SiteCode] IS NULL) OR ([SiteCode] =
>   @param7)) AND   ((@param8 = 1 AND [FirstName] IS NULL) OR ([FirstName]
>   = @param9)) AND

etc up to @param60 for all 31 columns.  When I look at the UpdateCommand->Parameters->Result Views the values for each of the columns appears correct thus satisfying the conditions expected, however the @param4, @ param6 @param8 etc are all showing a value of 0 which does not meet the WHERE condition of the command.  This is way over my understanding but it seems the command builder is generating parameters (@param4 @param6 @param8 up to @param60 being the even numbers) that are set to 0 based on some environmental setting to do with concurrency that I have not established. Where would I find further information to help track down what I am missing?
Thanks Brad

Edit:
After hours and hours of searching and testing without any success I decided to start with a blank Sqlite database and keep adding a column to the datatable then test the modify/save, this worked well until I added a Date column (called "LastCleaned"). At this point I got the concurrency error even though I was not changing the "LastCleaned" column.  It appears my problem occurs when sqlite reads a date (which was created in SQLite Expert Personal as a SQL type of "DATE") and then tries to save it back to the database.
Does this make sense to anyone?
Thanks again Brad

Comment: Always share exact text of the exception message.  A summary explanation is rarely sufficient.  Indicate exactly which line the error occurs on.  (Edit the question... don't just put that info in comments.)

Comment: Update:  I have found that the  sqlite update command generated by the command builder sets a condition that each sourcecolumn has a (@paramx = 1) however the in the parameterlist these params are all set to 0?

Comment: Okay, but just like my previous request to add precise exception details, this latest information comes without necessary details to do anything about it. If you mention the update command, then edit the question and add those details. Because we don't know your schema, a single parameter example is not enough to really know what's going on.

Comment: Does the exception you showed have an inner exception?  Are there more details coming from the sqlite via more exception details?